# I want to make a linked list by dummy headed But why the code is printing reverse!!. Here is my code

Tags: python, data-structures, linked-list

I want to make a linked list by dummy headed circular but I can't understand why the code is printing reverse.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value, next, prev ):
        self.data = value
        self.next = next
        self.prev = prev

class DoublyList:
    def __init__(self, c):
        self.head = Node(None,None,None) #instance variable
        self.head.prev = self.head.next = self.head

        for i in c:
            store = Node(i, None, None)
            store.next = self.head.next
            store.prev = self.head
            self.head.next = store
            store.next.prev = store

    def showList(self):
        n = self.head.next
        while n !=self.head:
            print(n.data, end=' ')
            n = n.next
a = [10,20,30,40,50,60]
l1 = DoublyList(a)
l1.showList()
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that shows how you use this `DoublyList` class.

Comment: i updated the code with example

Comment: I suggest you add `print()` statements to `DoublyList.__init__()` to find where your code doesn't do what you expect. Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for more tips on debugging.

Comment: first use `print()` to see what you have in variables and which part of code is executed. It is called `"print debuging"`. Maybe you visit elements on list in wrong order OR you put items in wrong order. With `print()` you should see it.

Comment: you always add new Node to `self.head` so last node is always as first - you add them in wrong order.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works:

```py
class DoublyList:
    def __init__(self, c):
        self.head = Node(None,None,None) #instance variable
        self.head.prev = self.head.next = self.head
        for i in c:
            store = Node(i, None, None)
            store.prev = self.head.prev
            store.next = self.head
            self.head.prev = store
            store.prev.next = store
            print(store,"         ",store.prev)
            if store.prev==self.head:
                self.head.next=store  #first node
```

There were 2 problems with your original code:

#### 1:

You switched the prev and the next attribute. This is an easy fix: just change all `prev` attributes into `next` and vice versa.

#### 2:

When executing the code after that, you might have noticed that there's nothing printed at all. This happens because your `self.head.next` remains setted to `self.head`, making your program not even start the while loop. To fix it, you've to find the first node in your for loop, and set `self.head.next` to it

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to add each subsequent node *after* the last node in the list, it should be inserted just *before* the sentinel (`head`) node.

I would also suggest the following change to the Node constructor, so that it defaults to making a self-reference when the second and third argument are not provided:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value, nxt=None, prev=None):
        self.data = value
        self.next = nxt or self
        self.prev = prev or self
```

And make good use of those parameters when you *do* pass arguments for them:

```
class DoublyList:
    def __init__(self, c):
        self.head = Node(None)

        for i in c:
            store = Node(i, self.head, self.head.prev)
            store.prev.next = store.next.prev = store
```